# Qt: Get QAudioDeviceInfo for input device by name

Tags: qt

Is there a Qt function to get an audio input device by it's `QString` name? Related functions I've found:

- [QAudioDeviceInfo QAudioDeviceInfo::defaultInputDevice()](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qaudiodeviceinfo.html#defaultInputDevice)
- [QList<QAudioDeviceInfo> QAudioDeviceInfo::availableDevices()](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qaudiodeviceinfo.html#availableDevices).
- [void QAudioRecorder::setAudioInput(const QString &name)](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qaudiorecorder.html#setAudioInput)

`QAudioRecorder::setAudioInput()` is close to what I want but AFAIK there is no way I can get a `QAudioDeviceInfo` out of `QAudioRecorder`.

I could iterate through the `QList` returned by `QAudioDeviceInfo::availableDevices()`  but was hoping for something better.

Comment: There is no better way, you should iterate through availableDevices and check deviceName

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As @demonplus suggested in comment, Qt provides nothing. I'm just using:

```c++
QAudioDeviceInfo getAudioDevice(QString name) {
    QAudioDeviceInfo device;
    QList<QAudioDeviceInfo> devices = 
        QAudioDeviceInfo::availableDevices(QAudio::AudioInput);
    for(int i = 0; i < devices.size(); ++i) {
        if(devices.at(i).deviceName() == name) {
            device = devices.at(i);
            break;
        }
    }
    return device;
}

QAudioDeviceInfo myDevice = getAudioDevice("default");
if(myDevice.isNull()) {
    qCritical("Device not found");
}
```